# in mysql jdbc does auto commit affect all connections?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, connection-pooling, autocommit

when using a connection pool,
will setting a connection's autocommit = false
affect this connection only?

if i close this connection without setting autocommit = true
and get a new connection will this connection's policy be set to autocommit= true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer would to the point be: "depends on the connection pool used".

However, if I was a connection pool, I would have restored the autocommit state as per the initial configuration. I think that other connection pools would do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Test scenario:

1. set autocommit=false
2. use transactions
3. close the connection without setting it back to autocommit=true

Outcome: when *this* particular connection is reused, **it still has autocommit=false** (other new connections have the default autocommit=true). So, once I kill *this* connection on the database side and call my code again, only then the pool gives me a fresh connection with the default autocommit=true.

Conclusion: it affects only *this* connection, but make sure you set it back to autocommit=true before closing! *(This is based on real testing, not an assumption)*

Note: this beahvior is noted here too: http://www.coderanch.com/t/583969/JDBC/databases/Tomcat-connection-pool-auto-commit

I use JDBC with Tomcat7, Java 1.7, MySQL5.6, Connector/J 5.1.